# Record Sound in Windows Server 2016 VM - Google Cloud Platform

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to record sound in a 2016 windows server virtual machine. After I initialize the virtual machine and install audacity (or other sound recording software) I receive this error.

```
Error while opening sound device. Please check the recording device settings 
and the project sample rate.
```

In recording device settings there are no devices listed.

Can I provision an instance with a soundcard or can I download a virtual sound card?

Comment: From what microphone or device do you want to record sound?

Comment: I want to record from the speakers. EX: the audio played in a YouTube video.

Answer (score 3):

Check out step 4 in this [article about using Google Cloud Platform for Cloud Gaming](https://medium.com/@cloudymike/using-google-cloud-platform-for-cloud-gaming-on-chrome-os-b1618cc34d8c) to create a virtual sound card for your VM.

Answer (score 1):

To enable sound on the Virtual Desktop Windows and to be able to hear via RDP proceed as indicated (all the operations listed below are to be carried out only on the Cloud Server and not on the local Client):

1. access the Cloud Server via RDP
2. click on "Sound" on the control panel and turn on the "Windows Audio Service"
3. enable the audio redirection for the Remote Desktop section by following the steps below:

   3.1 From the "Start" menu click "Run", type "mmc.exe" and press "OK"
   a "Console Root" window will open,

   3.2 from the heading "File" click "Add/Remove Snap-in"
   select the heading "Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration", click "Add >" and then press "OK"
   double click on the heading "RD Session Host Configuration: server-name" which appears under "Console Root"

   3.3. In the window that opens, select the tab "Client Settings" and remove the check mark symbol on the item "Audio and video playback" and then press "OK"

**Note**:

- for the changes to take effect you need to "Log off" and reconnect via RDP
- It should be remembered that to be able to hear sound of the Cloud Server (during the RDP connection) the Client needs to have a sound card and a working audio output.